# Issue in Mapping for Hibernate JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

I have a datamodel, which has:

- a `User` entity which has a few fields specific to 2 users in the application
- another entity `UserDetails`, which contains details specific to one particular type of user in the application besides the fields in `User` entity

Both entities share the same primary key. I am new to JPA. What kind of mappings should be there between the two?

```java
@Entity
class User{
  @Id
  @Column(name="USER_ID")
  private int id;
}


@Entity
class UserDetails{
  @Id
  @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
  private User user;

  ...
}
```

The above mapping gives issues on fetching `UserDetails` for a particular `User`.

**It requires that both Entities share the same primary key USER_ID.**

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention the issues with the above mapping. It looks OK, but I would use a separate primary key for `UserDetails` table.

```
@Entity
class UserDetails{
  @Id
  private int id;

  @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
  private User user;

  ...
}
```

Also, it is a good practise to use [bidirectional relationships](http://fruzenshtein.com/bidirectional-many-to-one-association/), for eaiser navigation i.e. getting user details from `User`, you would just use `user.getUserDetails();` so in `User` class:

```
@Entity
class User{
  @Id
  @Column(name="USER_ID")
  private int id;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
  private UserDetails userDetails;
}
```

Comment: Actually the data model requires that both share the primary key that is USER_ID is the primary key for both entities. And on fetching the users list in above case I get an empty output, whereas the table in DB has rows in Users.

Answer (score 0):

In this case use `OneToOne` relationship. But make sure your database table `UserDetails`has foreign key relationship to `User` table. Use below code to implement it using `JPA` and `Hibernate`.

```
@Entity
class User{
  @Id
  @Column(name="USER_ID")
  private int id;

  // getters and setters
}


@Entity
class UserDetails{
  @Id
  @Column(name="USER_DETAILS_ID")
  private int userDetailsId;

  @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
  private User user;

  // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Actually the data model requires that both share the primary key that is USER_ID is the primary key for both entities. And on fetching the users list in the case mentioned by me, I get an empty output, whereas the table in DB has rows in Users.